# Validating and searching ip address

Tags: bash

I am trying to do two things: 1. Test ip address for validity. 2. search the ip address in a file with many ip address. "ips" is the file. This is what I have so far. Every time I run the script I get this: It does not matter if the ip address is in the file I always get "IP address NOT found, and saved". Please help. Thank you in advanced

```
$ ./test1
 IP address: 202
 Not Valid. Please re-enter the ip address
 IP address: 202.124.64.0
 IP address NOT found, and saved
 IP address: 109.234..232.0
 Not Valid. Please re-enter the ip address
 IP address: 109.234.232.0
 IP address NOT found, and saved
```

The script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 while true; do

 echo -e "IP address: \c"
 read ip

 function valid_ip()
 {
   local stat=1

     if [[ $ip =~ [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
        OIFS=$IFS
        IFS='.'
        ip=($ip)
        IFS=$OIFS
        [[ ${ip[0]} -le 255 && ${ip[1]} -le 255 && ${ip[2]} -le 255 \
           && ${ip[3]} -le 255 ]]
         stat=$?
     fi
     return $stat
 }

 if valid_ip $ip; then
    if grep 'valid_ip $ip' ips; then
       echo "IP address found, and saved"
      else
       echo "IP address NOT found, and saved"
    fi
   else
    echo "Not Valid. Please re-enter the ip address"
 fi

 done
```

Comment: Are you creating a function inside a `while` block?

Comment: I am new in this so if I am not doing it right, I would appreciate any advise. Thank you fedorqui

Comment: To start with, move the function declaration above the `while true` line, and within the function, refer to the parameter as $1, rather than $ip.  Also you're missing a right square bracket in the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your function like this:

```
valid_ip() {
   local stat=1
   ip="$1"
   if [[ $ip =~ [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
        OIFS=$IFS
        IFS='.'
        a=($ip)
        IFS=$OIFS
        [[ ${a[0]} -le 255 && ${a[1]} -le 255 && ${a[2]} -le 255 && ${a[3]} -le 255 ]]
        stat=$?
   fi
   return $stat
}
```

Then call it as:

```
 while true; do
 reap -p "Enter an IP address: " ip

 if valid_ip $ip; then
     echo "IP address found, and valid"
     break;
 else
    echo "Not Valid. Please re-enter the ip address"
 fi

 done
```

Answer (score 1):

Your quoting is off. `$` variables don't expand in single quotes in bash, so it's searching for the string `$ip`, not the ip address contained in the variable. So

```
if grep 'valid_ip $ip' ips; then
```

should be

```
if grep $(valid_ip "$ip") ips; then
```